# How to refactor "from X import Y" statement in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

If I use "convert to import X" on `from X import Y` statement, for some cases, it refuses to convert it saying that "name X is obscured, Y will become X.Y" - and I'm okay with that, but there's no "Accept" button, so I can not make those changes happen.

I'm using Community Edition `162.*` version (quite recent). That is actually education edition, but that must be similar to Community.

I have found the exact case when that happens:

```
   pkg/
       __init__.py
       a.py
       b.py
```

with the following content

```
// __init__.py
# unrelated imports or empty

// b.py
def func2():pass

// a.py
import pkg
from pkg.b import func2

func2()
```

in this case, the error rises when I try to convert `from pkg.b import func2` into `import pkg.b; pkg.b.func2()`, however, if I remove `import pkg` line from file `a.py`, everything starts working.

I do not quite understand why that happens.

Comment: Which version of PyCharm? And which edition? Enterprise or CE?

Comment: @fedepad , updated

Comment: Ok, because I have 2016.2.3 (the latest) 162.* CE, but I don't see this option...how do you trigger this refactoring? Doesn't appear when I select the import line...

Comment: @fedepad I hit `Alt-Enter` when text cursor is on the corresponding line

Comment: Ok, I tried and it works for me. For which cases doesn't work for you?

Comment: @fedepad updated question